# How do I append query string to url from a JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

I got a page with comments. I want the user to be able to sort those comments by `oldest` or `newest` by clicking on a link that show up in the comment section.

I am already preprocessing views via the url. So when the user browses to `book?id=20` it shows the book with the `id` of `20` from the database.

Going directly to `book?id=20&sort=oldest` already works. How do I get my JSP to append to the URL upon clicking?

The problem im having is that I can't hardcode them in: for example, if I just coded in `<a href="book?id=${param.id}&show=newest">Newest</a>` it will disrupt other query strings. What if the user is already at the URL `book?id=20&stars=5` (shows comments with the rating of 5 stars).

I'd like the JSP to just append onto the URL so that it includes any current queries, so for example: user is at currently at `book?id=20&stars=5`, user then clicks `sort by oldest`, then the JSP appends `&sort=oldest` making it `book?id=20&stars=5&sort=oldest`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with something like that:

```
<a href="book?id=${param.id}&show=newest" onclick="this.href=this.href+'&sort=oldest'">Newest</a>
```